# Why am I still getting pkg deprecation warnings?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

I'm still getting warnings about the old pkg tools being deprecated and saying I should switch to pkgng, despite the fact that I followed the directions to switch weeks ago.  I did the pkg2ng thing, and the old pkg can't even read the info anymore (shows as corrupt if I try).  My /etc/make.conf is set to use pkgng as well.  Yet, doing ports updates (via portmaster) I still see warnings about the old pkg system going away.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the message you are complaining about is this one:

```
pkg_install EOL is scheduled for 2014-09-01. Please consider migrating to pkgng
http://blogs.freebsdish.org/portmgr/2014/02/03/time-to-bid-farewell-to-the-old-pkg_-tools/
If you do not want to see this message again set NO_WARNING_PKG_INSTALL_EOL=yes in your make.conf
```

According to `Mk/bsd.port.mk` from ports, this message is only displayed if `WITH_PKGNG` is not set:

```
.if !defined(WITH_PKGNG) && !defined(NO_WARNING_PKG_INSTALL_EOL)
WARNING+=       "pkg_install EOL is scheduled for 2014-09-01. Please consider migrating to pkgng"
WARNING+=       "http://blogs.freebsdish.org/portmgr/2014/02/03/time-to-bid-farewell-to-the-old-pkg_-tools/"
WARNING+=       "If you do not want to see this message again set NO_WARNING_PKG_INSTALL_EOL=yes in your make.conf"
.endif
```

That is if your `/etc/make.conf` does not contain a valid:

```
WITH_PKGNG=yes
```

Comment: *should* is the operative word.  My /etc/make.conf is configured as listed, but I *do* still get those EOL warnings.  It's not just one machine either, I've got the same thing on all of the FreeBSD VMs/boxen that I keep updated.

Comment: Then what about your OS releases ? `pkg` version ? the exact content of your `/etc/make.conf` ? last time you upgraded your port  tree ?

Comment: FreeBSD 9.2 on all.  Pkg is the current version as of a couple days ago (I do OS update checks monthly and ports upgrades every couple of weeks, sooner if aware of something with impact that we use).  "WITH_PKGNG=yes" is the entire contents of /etc/make.conf on a couple boxes, on others there are additional parameters.  I did find one with a typo (PKG2NG instead of PKGNG), but the rest were spelled correctly.

Comment: It's working now after some more ports updates.  One box had a typo in the make.conf, the others were fine.  I was fixing some balky updates and may have confused the system by following directions for the old pkg system instead of the new.

Comment: @Brian Knoblauch: glad to know ... as I started a couple of times from a fresh 9.2 and try to reproduce your issue without success ;)